# fast way to get value of keyup / keydown event

Tags: javascript

I'm using

```
String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)
```

to get the value of keyup / keydown event. but the result lags when keeping a key down (key sequence).
is there any faster way to get value of keyup / keydown event ?
note; I need a plain Javascript way.thanks in advance

Comment: The only improvement that I see is caching values. But tests show that it's more negative impact rather than improvement (see http://jsperf.com/cache-vs-no-cache-fromcharcode/2). Seems that it's the fastest way to use `String.fromCharCode`. Could be please write more about lagging or add more code? Maybe the problem is not there.

Answer (score 1):

FromCharKeycode is not a good idea to get values of characters, check the value of numbers? you see you're getting a for 1, b for 2 etc. a function for checking if the returned value is correct makes it more slower than getting the last character of input value.